# Bind INotifyPropertyChanged class as Property in another class

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a class that has a fairly long running process that I want the GUI to give progress on.

The class has a property called Progress that is a class implementing INotifyPropertyChanged. I'm using a BusyWorker and bind the class's Progress property to it's datacontext, but whenever the progress changes the BusyWorker does not show anything. I don't know if I'm making any sense here, so here's some code:

The class in question:

```
public class MyClass
{
  public Progress MyProgress { get; set; }

  public void Run()
  {
    MyProgress = new Progress();
    MyProgress.Status = "Initialising";
    // Do stuff, update progress, etc.
  }
}

public class Progress : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private string status;

  public string Status
  {
    get { return status; }
    set
    {
      status = value;
      OnPropertyChanged("Status");
    }
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  private void OnPropertyChanged(string info)
  {
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
      PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
  }
}
```

XAML:

```
// ...
<xctk:BusyIndicator HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="busyIndicator" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" BusyContent="{Binding}">
    <xctk:BusyIndicator.BusyContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Margin="4">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Status}" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </xctk:BusyIndicator.BusyContentTemplate>
</xctk:BusyIndicator>
// ...
```

XAML.CS:

```
MyClass test = new MyClass();
BusyIndicator.DataContext = test.MyProgress;
BusyIndicator.IsBusy = true;
test.Run();
```

If I run it like this, and stop at the `OnPropertyChanged` call, `PropertChanged` is always null. If I make a separate Progress object in my xaml.cs it works just fine, but I want my 'Run' method to handle this. Is this even possible?

Comment: Where you updated progress status?

Comment: The BusyIndicator is bound to MyProgress, so when I set MyProgress.Status to any value the BusyIndicator should pick up the change and display it accordingly.

Comment: You are not binding to the Status property anywhere. That's why your OnPropertyChanged will be null always. Try changing `Text="{Binding Header}"` to `Text="{Binding Status}"`

Comment: Sorry, forgot to change that after copy pasting the code. It actually is bound to status.

Comment: Can you check if MyProgress is not null?

Comment: MyProgress is not null, the call to OnPropertyChange works, the PropertyChanged event is null.

Comment: PropertyChanged is null means that the binding on Status is not working / incorrectly set. This is trial and error, but I would start by commenting out the datatemplate and change the binding of the BusyIndicator to `<xctk:BusyIndicator HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="busyIndicator" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" BusyContent="{Binding Status}">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Problem is you are assigning Data Context before calling the run method which means by the time you are assigning data context "MyProgress" Object is "Null".. so data context is null before calling the "Run" method.. you are calling the Run method which creates an instance for "MyProgress" but since your "MyClass" is not "INotifyPropertyChanged" its not able to notify the data context change...

Solution is: Try creating MyProgress instance in the constructor of MyClass.. so by the time of assigning data context will not be null and the in the run method don't create any instance just update the status property..

Something like this

```
public class MyClass
{
  public Progress MyProgress { get; set; }

  public MyClass()
  {
    MyProgress = new Progress();
  }

  public void Run()
  {    
    MyProgress.Status = "Initialising";
    // Do stuff, update progress, etc.
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah, I got it. I did create the instance of MyProgress inside the constructor, but the Run method overwrote that instance. I removed that from the Run method and now it seems to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<xctk:BusyIndicator HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="busyIndicator" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" BusyContent="{Binding}">
<xctk:BusyIndicator.BusyContentTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Margin="4">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Status}" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Left" DataContext="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=BusyIndicator}}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</xctk:BusyIndicator.BusyContentTemplate>
```

// ...

Comment: Sorry, that's not it. It is bound correctly, I just copy/pasted it wrong here. When I create a separate Progress object outside MyClass it works, it just that it doesn't work when bound to the progress property in MyClass

Comment: Ok, try to set DataContext for TextBox same as DataContext for BusyIndicator. I changed example

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:
*.xaml

```
<xctk:BusyIndicator HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="busyIndicator" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" IsBusy="True">
                <xctk:BusyIndicator.BusyContentTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Margin="4">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Test.MyProgress.Status, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </xctk:BusyIndicator.BusyContentTemplate>
            </xctk:BusyIndicator>
```

*.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MyClass Test { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        Test = new MyClass();
        InitializeComponent();
        Test.Run();
    }
}

public class MyClass
{
    public Progress MyProgress { get; set; }

    public void Run()
    {
        MyProgress = new Progress();
        MyProgress.Status = "Initialising";
        // Do stuff, update progress, etc.
    }
}

public class Progress : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string status;

    public string Status
    {
        get { return status; }
        set
        {
            status = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Status");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
    }
}
```